# Parameter inside SESSION does not appear inside other php files

Tags: php, joomla, session-variables

I've got two files, like these two:

```
<?php  
session_start();

class test{
    public function login($code){ 

        $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
        $db    = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select(array('id'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__users'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('code') . " = " . $db->quote($code));

        $db->setQuery($query);//execute query             
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();//get results

        if ($results[0] != null) {
            $this->createSession($results[0]);
            header("refresh:2;url=second_file.php");
        } 

        return json_encode($results);
    }

    public function createSession($LoginInfo){ 
        $_SESSION['userId']=$LoginInfo->id;
    }
}

?>
```

and another php file like this:

```
<?php 
 session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
  <?php 
    echo $_SESSION['userId'];
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the second page seems like that there is no information inside the session and i'm unable to get "userId" parameter.

PS: the first class php file is called by another php file where there is something like this:

```
require_once('test.class.php');
$mainframe = new test
if ($_GET['code']!=null) echo $mainframe->login($_GET['code']);
```

Where am I doing wrong? thanks.

PPS: All those file are hosted inside altervista.org and there is Joomla CMS installed.

Comment: Joomla looks after your session, and if like most other frameworks that do that they destroy the `$_SESSION` so you dont use it by mistake. See https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getSession

Comment: I think that I've found a solution, I had to use "$app->redirect('second_page.php');" instead  "header("refresh:2;url=second_file.php");" and I have changed the usage of  "$_SESSION" with Joomla's "$session =JFactory::getSession(); session->set( 'id', '1' ); $session->get( 'id' )"